# How to update database after changing in Seed() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to change some code in Seed() method creating data and when I write `Update-Database` command in Console and press 'Enter', in result I have the same data in database like before changing.

For example when I have to change from age = 15 to age = 20. I save changes and put "Update-Database" command. But in database I have still age = 15. Only one option that I know and working is delete Migrations folder, changing name of database in ConnectionStrings, and then put command `Enable-Migrations`, `Add-migration`, `Update-Database` but I think is no optimal solution. This is my Seed() method below:

```
protected override void Seed(Repository.Models.OglContext context)
        {
            var store = new UserStore<User>(context);
            var manager = new UserManager<User>(store);
            if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "Admin"))
            {
                var user = new User { UserName = "Admin", Age = 115 };
                var adminresult = manager.Create(user, "12345678");

                if (adminresult.Succeeded)
                    manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }
        }
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, this is EF. For example I have to change int age = 15 to age = 20. I save changes and put "Update-Database" command. But in database I have still age = 15.

Comment: "and the update is contained in a registered migration?"... How can I check this one?

Comment: post your seed method

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `context.SaveChanges();` otherwise the data will not be stored!

- If you have more than one migration level then you have to use DbSet.AddOrUpdate()
- Alternatively, you can also update the database during the migration within the migration file like below:

  ```
  public partial class MigrationFile : DbMigration
  {
      public override void Up()
      {
          // Add or update the data
          Sql("UPDATE ...");
          Sql("INSERT ...");
      }

      public override void Down()
      {
          // Remove Data
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `else` statement to edit the user when it already exists:

```
var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "Admin");
if (user == null))
{
    user = new User { UserName = "Admin", Age = 115 };
    var adminresult = manager.Create(user, "12345678");

    if (adminresult.Succeeded)
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
}
else
{
    user.Age = 20;
}
context.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: It return error:
            var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "Admin");
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = new Uzytkownik { UserName = "Admin", Age = 115 };
                var adminresult = manager.Create(user, "12345678");

                if (adminresult.Succeeded)
                    manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                user.Age = 2054;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();